# Can't connect Spring Boot and MS SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, spring, spring-boot, mssql-jdbc

I need to access to a MS SQL Server 2012 which is located on localhost. The problem is that whenever I try to send a HTTP POST request (which calls a method that writes inside the Database), I get the following error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'admin'. ClientConnectionId:e2b2c522-55c6-406f-9762-fcd36e8472d1
```

Any suggestion?

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/depiva_test_localhost
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.second.jdbcUrl=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=BetonWinSQL;
spring.datasource.second.username=admin
spring.datasource.second.password=mypassword
```

[image: I use the admin account]

[image: Roles associated with the account]

Comment: Can you update your question to show how you're using the `spring.datasource.second.*` properties to define a `DataSource` bean?

Answer (score 0):

You are using settings for PostgreSQL instead of MSSQL
Here is how it should look

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=springbootdb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=Projects@123
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop
```

https://springframework.guru/configuring-spring-boot-for-microsoft-sql-server/

Comment: I have two database connections. One is for a PostgreSQL server and the other one is for MS SQL Server.